# Using Groovy beta 3, but can't find a Spock version that will work it

Tags: groovy, version, spock

I'm using Groovy beta 3 to use the method references feature etc

I can't find a Spock version that seems to work with the Groovy 3 beta.

Is there a test version of Spock that works with the Groovy 3 codelines?

I tried this in my Gradle build, exclude the default Groovy 2.5 dependency, but this gives a build failure:

```
testCompile (group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.3-groovy-2.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all'
    }
```

Comment: There are snapshot versions of Spock https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/997 not tried them, but they should work

Comment: i tried jitpack but couldnt resolve the snapshot, so instead I went to oss.sonatype by adding `maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }` to my repositories.  I could then refresh the dependencies to get this `testCompile (group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.3-groovy-2.5-SNAPSHOT')`.  so far i think this appears to working with groovy 3 beta as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

Spock supports Groovy 3 starting with version [2.0-M2](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M2/release_notes.html).

For Gradle it should be enough to add a Spock's JAR dedicated for Groovy 3:

```
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0')
```

and enable JUnit Platform:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

As a person who developed support for Groovy 3 in Spock I gathered various aspects (including caveats) relating migration from Spock 1.3 to 2.0 in a [blog post](https://blog.solidsoft.info/2020/01/02/migrating-spock-1-3-tests-to-spock-2-0/) - it might be worth to read it :-).